# How to add all folders in a treeview as nodes with nesting

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a set of directories under a folder. The directory structure isn't 100% consistent (e.g. under A there maybe folders within folders but not under B).

I need to bind all the folders in a treeview with appropriate nesting (e.g. C:\a\b nests under C:\a).

Is there an easy way, or even free treeview, that would let me do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    treeView.Nodes.Add(GetDirectoryNodes(@"C:\TEST"));
}

private static TreeNode GetDirectoryNodes(string path)
{
    var node = new TreeNode(path);

    var subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Select(d => GetDirectoryNodes(d)).ToArray();
    node.Nodes.AddRange(subDirs);

    return node;
}
```

Just uses `Directory.GetDirectories()` from `System.IO` in a recursive method to build the node hierarchy, and drop this into the TreeView.

EDIT - adding exclusion mechanism as per comments (and converted expression to Linq, which is clearer in this case):

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    treeView.Nodes.Add(GetDirectoryNodes(@"C:\TEST", new string[] { @"C:\TeST\C", @"C:\TEST\E" }));
}

private static TreeNode GetDirectoryNodes(string path, string[] exclusions)
{
    var node = new TreeNode(Path.GetFileName(path));

    var subDirs = (from d in Directory.GetDirectories(path)
                   where !exclusions.Contains(d,StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                   select GetDirectoryNodes(d,exclusions)).ToArray();

    node.Nodes.AddRange(subDirs);
    return node;
}
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you so much! All I need to now is parse the foldername to just get the name of the last folder (E.g. get testADD from C:\test\1\2\testdd).

Comment: Ah, I read the question as wanting full path each time - still easy, just replace var node = new TreeNode(path); with var node = new TreeNode(Path.GetFileName(path));

Comment: BTW, how can I exclude certain folders from the top level? So I am searching from C:\Tests, but don't want to include the Photos album in the results and not display a node for a skipped folder.

Comment: You could pass in a list of excluded directories, then add a where clause like .Where(d => !exclusions.Contains(d)) to the GetDirectories expression

Comment: Have an example of this? I'm assuming you mean a where clause on the path string.